# Options: Letting it expire or sell when profiting?

Tags: options, call-options, put-options, option-strategies

Do you let your options expire or would you sell it before you let it expire if you're profiting (meaning you're in the green - market is going towards the correct direction you anticipated).

If you let it expire is it worthless? I'm still confused as to how options work exactly. Lately I've only been selling it before it expires if I'm making money from options.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is slightly ambiguous.  Are you asking whether it's better to sell or exercise an option when it is *about to expire* or whether it's better to sell a profitable option vs. waiting when there's still meaningful time before expiration? (I can probably help with either - I used to run an options desk, but the explanations are different.)

Comment: Only OTM options expire worthless, if you're Short, you keep the money on expiration. If Long it's safer to spend a small amount to buy back before expiration, reducing risk (exposure). If you're "Hedging" with options, they are your insurance and you are Long them, and you hold or roll out to a longer time frame or Strike price. Assume ITM options will be exercised, if you're Long your account will be credited. If you're Short your account will be charged. If you're Long options and they are ITM, sell/hold requires your judgment call. If ITM a Strike or more, Hedge or Sell.

Comment: Can you elaborate: "If Long it's safer to spend a small amount to buy back before expiration, reducing risk (exposure)". If you are already long the option, what are you buying back? buy back only applies if you are short, correct?

Answer (score 4):

Check the rules with your broker. *Usually* if it expires in the money, the broker would exercise it. But you need to check with *your* broker about their rules on the matter.